# Deleting text after it has shown openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, text

I'm writing a 3D game in C++ and OpenGL.

What I would like to do is when a player collides with an object a small bit of text shows up on the screen and then disappears after a few seconds.

I know how to draw the text itself to the screen on the collision. My problem is I don't know how to delete the text after a few seconds.

I am current using this function to draw text to the screen:

```
void Gui::drawStrokeText(_In_ const string& p_string, _In_ int p_x, _In_ int p_y, _In_ int p_z)
 {
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(p_x, p_y, p_z);
  glScalef(0.25f, -0.25f, p_z);
  glColor4f(200/255.f, 200/255.f, 200/255.f, 128/255.f);

  for (int i = 0; i < p_string.size(); ++i)
  {
      glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN , p_string[i]);
  }
  glPopMatrix();
 }
```

So to clarify what is the better way to delete the text from the screen?

The whole class can be found [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3245)

Comment: Probably create a struct that has a life timer as an instance variable. In the render function, you would loop through a global list of all the text objects, and if its life timer is greater than zero, display it, otherwise remove it from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you must have some kind of timer to check if you must draw something in this frame (a single step in main loop) or time expired and you must hide it (equal to simply not draw).

Here is a fast (pseudo)code example (might contain errors! Look approach, not syntax):

```
Timer* g_Timer; // timer, for example wrapped std::chrono or Windows QueryPerformanceCounter()
Renderer* g_Renderer;

int main()
{
    ...
    while( running ) // main loop
    {
        ...
        g_Timer->Tick(); // calculate delta time, FPS, etc.
        g_Renderer->RenderOneFrame();
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class GameObject
{
public:
    void ShowText( const std::wstring& text, const float currentTime, const float showDuration )
    {
        hideTextTime = currentTime + showDuration;
        collisionText = text;
    }

    float WhenWeMustHideText() const { return hideTextTime; }
    std::wstring GetCollisionText() const { return collisionText; }
private:
    float hideTextTime;
    std::wstring collisionText;

};

void RenderOneFrame()
{
    ...
    float time = g_Timer->GetTime(); // time elapsed since game start in milliseconds
    float dt = g_Timer->GetDelta(); // time elapsed since previous frame in milliseconds
    ...

    for(int i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i)
    {
        // check collision somehow
        if( object[i]->HasCollision() )
        {
            object->ShowText( L"Boom!", time , 5000.0f );
        }

        // check if we must draw text or just forget to do this ("hide")
        if ( time <= object[i]->WhenWeMustHideText() )
        {
            g_Renderer->DrawText(object[i]->GetCollisionText(), object[i]->GetPosition() + offset);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!